# Why don't more Computer Viruses simply flash the Bios with malicious software

Tags: windows, bios, virus

Most Viruses can be removed by simply wiping the harddrive and reinstalling windows.
So why don't more viruses create a payload and flash it to the BIOS chip? That way the can just redownload the virus on every boot without the user being able to remove it.
So why isn't the bios used as an attack vector more often?

Comment: It's a dead-end attack.  Once infected, that PC can't be used to infect any other computers.  How is the virus supposed to spread itself?  It's not  a virus, but just malware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a virus simply cannot.

Flashing the BIOS requires administrative access, something a virus usually can't gain.

In addition, each BIOS is different, and flashing a BIOS means that you need to know on beforehand what the target is going to be. Sure, you can create a virus of 1GB and contain 1000 different BIOSes but developing something like that is going to take so much resources, and the chance of your virus actually landing is so small, its just not worth the effort, not to mention that the lifespan of a BIOS is about 3 to 5 years, given that by time motherboards with those BIOSes are usually replaced by newer motherboards that have a different BIOS.

If someone wants to target a specific pc, it is much easier to hack into the system and destroy it remotely, if that is what you want to achieve, than to program a virus and hope that it infects the target machine.

And lastly, lets say it was as easy as this. What would the purpose of the virus be? It needs to spread itself, not keep infecting the host. You are talking about malware here, not a virus. Malware is meant to keep sending data back to its master servers collecting data, or maybe a form of ransomware (still not a virus). But the same thing applies here as well. You can't mass-target all systems due to how different the BIOSes are and how hard it is to gain access to them. If you target one system instead, a hacker will be much more successful than launching malware and hoping it gets to its target.

Answer (score 5):

Because flashing firmware is anything but simple.

In UEFI, A firmware update is always verified before flash, even pre-boot, so the resulting bios must be well-formed for UEFI spec and for the manufacturer hardware, or it will fail and not be written.

Many modern systems implement dual-bios, to protect and recover in the case of a bad flash.

Modern [UEFI bios provide secure verification to the OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_restriction#Secure_boot), such that the OS can require known certificates and signatures prior to boot.

[Intel Boot Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_vPro#IBG) is a CPU extension that will prevent boot with illegal firmware.

There are tens of thousands combinations of hardware components, so the attacker would need to maintain a huge repository of well-crafted malicious firmwares. This kind of attack is restricted to nation-state actors.

So, these attacks cannot scale, require huge effort and sophistication, and can be recovered from with some ease.

Now on your comments for storage persistence, understand that firmware code is not stored in the same place or way as its configuration. a firmware flash is all or nothing, so a piece of malware would not be able to add itself to a running configuration. the CMOS storage for configuration will not store binary executable info, and the OS is not able to write to CMOS anyway, it must be done by the Firmware itself.

Note that the real world value of implementing firmware malcode would be to implement rootkit/bootkit code at the very lowest level of the OS stack, and keep the system from realizing it is there, which is highly sophisticated stuff. that or simple brute force denial of service, which would be more easily performed in other ways.

Comment: wouldn't this also prevent custom firmware in general?

Comment: yes in fact it does. see some discussion about that here:  https://www.pcworld.com/article/2883903/how-intel-and-pc-makers-prevent-you-from-modifying-your-pcs-firmware.html When secure boot was first implemented for windows 10, MS wanted all OEMs to lock UEFI to Windows via certs. Ubuntu had some initial difficulty, but eventually MS backed off a little. this kind of lock is great for the average consumer, but can really make life harder for the tech enthusiast.

Comment: Note that I'm not saying that someone couldn't craft a specialized malware to flash Tom-down-the-streets ABit IP35Pro revision 2 motherboard in his custom system he runs OpenBSD on, but unless you are really interested in Tom, why would you bother?